# Intersection of the three circles

Tags: geometry

With the center at each of the vertices of an equilateral triangle with 2 cm on the side, three circles with a 2 cm radius are drawn. What is the area of intersection of the three circles?

[image]

I did the drawing, but it was out of scale. Can anyone give a hint?

Comment: Can you use integration?

Comment: @ajotatxe Seriously? Isn't there something more elementary?

Comment: integration is fairly elementary

Comment: you need to draw an accurate diagram first. You will see an easier way to solve.

Comment: The triangle of the figure is not even equilateral. Use the 'regular polygon' tool.

Comment: @MathLover Yes, I said it was out of scale. How do you think drawing it well would help me resolve the issue?

Comment: Because you have not observed without diagram that for any given circle, the other two circles pass through its center. That is a big step forward.  You need to make a fair attempt at the question. Just posting it here for others to solve for you is not the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you draw your picture accurately, you will see that your intersection is made of the original triangle plus three equal segments of circle. The area of the triangle is $A_1=\sqrt{3}$ and the area of one of the segments is
$$
A_2=\textrm{Area of sector}-\textrm{Area of triangle}=2\pi/3-\sqrt{3}.
$$
Therefore the area of the intersection is
$$
A=A_1+3A_2=2\pi-2\sqrt{3}.
$$

Comment: OP asked for a hint and you gave the whole solution

Comment: @MathLover Good point. I am sometimes wondering, are we ethically allowed to modify an answer by taking out the actual solution but leaving the steps intact?

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Try with this figure: [image] You should see how to solve the problem more easily.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to start with a correct figure here:

[image]